# Plural de pólder

Tags: número-gramatical

Um [pólder](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%B3lder) é uma região baixa e plana, pantanosa ou conquistada ao mar e protegida por diques.

Qual destas opções é correta para o plural?

- [pólderes](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/p%C3%B3lderes)
- [pôlderes](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%B4lderes)

Comment: Assim sem qualquer referência eu diria que é *pólderes*, pelo menos em Português de Portugal, a opção *pôlderes* parece mais uma grafia de Português do Brasil.

Comment: Os próprios links do Priberam que usaste indicam _Grafia em Portugal pólder_. Estás interessado em qual dialeto do Português?

Comment: @gmauch muito obrigado pela resposta, na variante Europeia. Mas repara que o plural no priberam apresenta com acento circunflexo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com o Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum da Língua Portuguesa, criado na sequência do Acordo Ortográfico, temos duas variantes (nos links abaixo é preciso clicar em «ver flexão» para ver o plural):

> Norma europeia: [*o póder, os pólderes*](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=63625&highlight=p%C3%B3lder)
>
> Norma brasileira: [*o pôlder, os pôlderes*](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=145539&highlight=p%C3%B3lder)

O [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=63625&highlight=%5Ep%C3%B3lder$) dá a mesma informação.

Os dicionários que consultei mostram os plurais apenas quando estes são irregulares (por exemplo, *caráter, carateres*). Ora o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e o dicionário Houaiss (edição portuguesa, com entrada *pólder*) não indicam o plural na entrada *pólder*, o que significa que, de acordo com as fontes acima, o entendem como regular, *pólderes* e não *pôlderes*. Do mesmo modo, os dicionários brasileiros [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/p%C3%B4lder) e [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=p%C3%B4lder) não apresentam o plural na entrada *pôlder*. O dicionário da Academia tem no entanto *pólderes* num exemplo (itálico meu):

> **pólder** [póɫdɛr]. *s. m.* (Do neer. *polder*) *Geog.* Região pantanosa ou conquistada ao mar, drenada e protegida por diques, destinada à agricultura e à habitação. *Os **pólderes** são típicos da Holanda, ocupando cerca de um terço do seu território.*

Há portanto um engano no Priberam: [diz não encontrar *pólderes* na norma europeia](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%B3lderes) e sugere *pôlderes*. Mas há aqui uma incoerência. O Priberam, tal como os outros dicionários, indica explicitamente os plurais irregulares. Vejam por exemplo [*caráter, carateres*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/car%C3%A1ter). Indica o plural mesmo quando a irregularidade é meramente fonética e não gráfica: por exemplo, [*miolo* |ô|, *miolos* |ó|](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/miolo). Mas se procurarmos [*pólder*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%B3lder), indica-nos os singulares nas normas europeia e brasileira, e não indica os plurais, ao contrário do que deveria fazer se o plural na norma europeia fosse irregular. Já lhes enviei um email.

Comment: Isto é que é serviço publico, parabéns!

Answer (score 2):

De forma simples e direta, seja a grafia **pôlder** <sup>português brasileiro</sup> ou **pólder** <sup>português europeu</sup>, ambas são substantivos paroxítonos terminados em *R* que, assim como os terminados em *Z*, têm suas formas plurais acrescentando-se **es** ao final.

Referência: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural#Regras_especiais)